# trying to write a function that find the combined result of n many 6 sided die

Tags: python, function, numpy-ndarray

trying to create a function that will add the sum when n number of dies are rolled once.
I have this so far but get a name error saying n is not defined any advice would be helpful

```
    import numpy as np
    def dice_rolln(n):
      np.random.seed(0)
      x = [np.random.randint(1, 7) for _ in range(n)]
      return sum[x]
```

Comment: you surely have a problem when you call your function. how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your function has two problems:

1. You're seeding the RNG the same way each time, which means you'll get the same results each time.
2. Your syntax for calling the `sum` function is incorrect.  Functions are called with `()`, not `[]`.

Here's a simple implementation using `random.randint`:

```
>>> import random
>>> def roll_nd6(n: int) -> int:
...     return sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n))
...
>>> roll_nd6(1)
5
>>> roll_nd6(10)
40
>>> roll_nd6(10)
34
```

Comment: thank you i didn't even realise it was outputting the same value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
import numpy as np
def dice_rolln(n):
      np.random.seed(0)
      x = [np.random.randint(1, 7) for _ in range(n)]
      return sum(x)
```

is you looking for this??

Comment: this has fixed the issue

Comment: just change the `return sum[x]` to `return sum(x)`.